# Utilizando Resolve no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou utilizando resolve para verificar se o utilizador esta logado, da seguinte forma:

```
routeProvider.
//...
.when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl',
            resolve: {
                auth: function ($q, Session) {
                    var userInfo = Session.getUserInfo();
                    if (userInfo) {
                        return $q.when(userInfo);
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

A minha dúvida é, o que faz o **$q.when(userInfo);** no código acima?

Pelo que entendi, deveria passar a variável "userInfo" como parâmetro no evento "routeChangeSucess", certo?

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", 
  function ($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (userInfo) {
        console.log(userInfo);
    });
    //...
```

Repare que tenho no código acima um console.log, porém ao verificar a console do Firefox, não me retorna os dados do utilizador mas sim o seguinte:

> Object { name="$routeChangeSuccess", targetScope=h, defaultPrevented=false, mais...}

O que está errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o que está errado são os parâmetros do `$routeChangeSuccess`, eles devem ser:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous) {
```

Por isso o log mostra este objeto:

> Object { name="$routeChangeSuccess", targetScope=h, defaultPrevented=false, mais...}

Sobre o `$q.when`, ele nada mais faz do que do que receber uma *promise* ou um objeto qualquer e retornar uma *promise*.
Se este objeto não for uma *promise*, o `when` faz um *wrap* dele numa *promise* e chama o `resolve`.

Comment: Repare que no "resolve" eu criei o objecto "userInfo", como faço para ter acesso ao objecto no routeChangeSuccess?

Comment: Sugiro alterar os parâmetros para: `(event, args)` e debugar com o console o conteúdo de `args` para ver onde está seu _userInfo_.

Comment: Certo, está no segundo parâmetro, locals -> auth, auth foi definido no "resolve".

Comment: Que bom que resolveu seu problema. Espero que se não aceitares esta como a resposta correta, pelo menos sinalize como útil. Obrigado